# Shared mailbox - users cannot create or view subfolders

Tags: exchange-2010, mailbox

I've setup a shared mailbox on our Exchange 2010/SBS2011 server. I've added some users as Full permission-users on this mailbox, and when they open Outlook/login to OWA the mailbox is automatically opened. Great stuff.

However, only the Inbox folder is visible, and the alternative to create a folder is grayed out. If they open the mailbox explicitly (for instance in OWA by clicking open other user's mailbox) they can see other folders, as well as create new ones. What configuration is needed to be able to view and create subfolders directly?

Answer (score 1):

You can give permissions on Inbox folder directly. It doesn't matter - shared mailbox it is or user mailbox.
Add Full permission for this folder to yourself.
Open the Inbox Folder properties - Permissions Tab.Choose the user and Check the checkbox Create Subfolder.
If you want to make the Subfolder visible - Open the Permission Tab of subfolder and check the Folder visible parameter.

Or you can use [Set-MailboxFolderPermission](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff522363%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx) cmdlet in powershell.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the inheritance type of the permissions as described in [this document](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124097%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx):

> The InheritanceType parameter specifies whether permissions are inherited by folders within the mailbox.

The options for this parameter can be seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectorysecurityinheritance.aspx). This appears to be the default, at least in our environment. To check if this is relevant to your scenario, you can do

```
Get-MailboxPermission <MailboxIdentity> | ft User,InheritanceType
```

to see what the `InheritanceType` flag is set to for your permissions entries on that shared mailbox. If they're not set to `All` then you may need to remove and re-add the permissions using

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "Ellen Adams" -User KevinKelly -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All
```

as an example.

The other thing we have had problems with is adding users to shared mailboxes directly. If you create a mail-enabled security group for that mailbox, grant it FullAccess to the mailbox and then add users to the security group, you may get better results.